# Opencart v1.5.4.1 - Modules not displaying

Tags: php, opencart

I am new to Opencart - switching from Magento, and I'm having a strange problem.
When I installed fresh, everything worked great. I cleared the products, everything fine. I started work on a custom design (by editing the css of an existing template) and changed the settings that I needed to, and now strangely, none of the modules work.

The modules for the homepage, and the backpages, aren't displaying. I did a check for the $modules variable on the template files and the variable was returned null. The modules are set up correctly and enabled in the home layout, the theme correctly calls the modules, and the settings -> design -> layout all have the correct route. I'm totally clueless as to what's going on. I'm not familiar enough with the code base and I've literally spent all day searching for a solution with no results.

Please let me know if I can provide additional information. The site isn't live yet, but it's living at batgearbeyond.net if looking at the opencart code helps at all.

Comment: Do You see some modules when going to backend `Extensions -> Modules`???

Comment: Yep, The modules were set up correctly and enabled. The problem was a setting in settings for the default layout. Thanks so much for your response. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this one out. In settings, somehow the default template was set to "default" instead of "home". I changed it to home and everything works lovely now! :)